# What is the equivalent of this DOFOR pseudocode in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I was following the following pseudocode from my textbook, and I was able to succesfully implement the function on the left in MATLAB. Now I am working on the function to the right, and I don't understand the following DOFOR line.

On the left, I implemented for i = 1 : n-1, but on the right.. What should the following 2 after n-2 represent?

[image]

Well, I ignored the second 2 and just ran my code as i=1:n-2 and I have an incorrect answer. ((The effected answer would be D, ignore et for now. That is a different equation.))

I've highlighted my solution versus the correct solution above:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

without knowing the book or the syntax this author is using we can only rely on our knowledge of the simpson's rule.

the simpson's rule is applied on each two consecutive points, so it is likely that the author's DOFOR roughly translates as following.

```
DOFOR i = start,stop,step
END DO
```

```matlab
for i = start:step:stop
end
```

hence in your code, this would be the right translation.

```matlab
for i = 1:2:n-2
...
end
```